# SSIS package runs without Config file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am New to SSIS config side. I have created one package with its config file. My Project placed into my account folder at server. but I created the config file which I placed at shared drive folder and also copy the mypackage.dtsx  file into another shared folder.

Now I have ran the package with dtexec.exe /f "mypackage.dtsx" without using config file even though it successfully run.

even I have changed some of the property into the config file and ran the package with use of the dtexec.exe command(mentioned above) and it was executed successfully.

So I have a question that, Do I need the config file at dtexec.exe command line because I can run my package by "dtexec.exe /f "mypackage.dtsx" " too?

I saw the syntax of dtexec.exe /f "package.dtsx" /config "myconfig.dtsconfig"

Please guide me...Does  the package contains the config file and its changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package will remember it's saved settings.  The benefit of a config file is that if you need to override/shange the settings that are contained in it, you can do that without needing to open, fix, and redeploy your package.  A config file is not ever necessary, it is just a convenience to you the developer, especially if your environment has a strict change management policy.  It is usually easier to change values in a config than to edit and redeploy a package under strict change managment.

**CLARIFICATION**

It appears from your question that you may be thinking that when you change the config it will change your package regardless of including your config in your execution.  All of the information from the config will be in the package at the time you save it, but it may differ from what is in the config.  If you run without config, you are running exactly what is saved in the package.  Package executions work like this:

1. Load package with all configurations from the saved .dtsx file
2. Check for configurations to load.
3. Load configuration in memory and overwrite values loaded from .dtsx package.
4. Execute.

This is simplified, and there are other things going on, but at the basic level this is accurate.

Comment: Thanks William...I will Discuss your view with my seniors and mark as an Answer Late...